# How should my users invite their Facebook friends to use my web app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an app where users interact in small private groups. We want to allow our users to invite their Facebook friends into a group. We previously posted a private link on a friend's timeline but Facebook disabled that last week: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

The apprequest dialog will not work as it is limited only to canvas and mobile applications:

> Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas, iOS and Android apps. Accepting a request on Canvas will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. For native mobile apps, accepting the request will direct the user to the app on their device if installed or to the appropriate location (Apple App Store or Google Play) to download the app otherwise.

from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

I was thinking of using Facebook Open Graph and creating an action and mention tagging, but that seems like a hack, and I dont think engagement will be as high.

What do you think the best way to do this is?

Thanks!

Comment: It is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 0):

Use Send to invite them in a private message.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog